# How can I get ServiceStack's Swagger implementation to use XML content-type?

Tags: json, xml, servicestack, swagger, swagger-ui

I have a VERY basic ServiceStack experiment that uses Swagger for generating documentation. The service can be used with several different content-types (XML, JSON, etc.):
[Default metadata page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jd4Ch.png)

However, I can only use content-type/json in the Swagger UI. Is there a configuration/attribute I can use, so that I can test the other content-types?
[Swagger UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JieZW.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change what Content Type Swagger uses, but ServiceStack Services provides [automatic Content Negotiation](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Routing#content-negotiation) so you can query for XML by using an `.xml` extension, e.g:

- /query.xml

Or specifying the format in the `?format=` query string:

- /query?format=xml

Or by adding the `Accept: application/xml` HTTP Request Header.

Swagger wont let change Content Types but you can use a more general purpose tool like [ServiceStack's Postman support](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Postman) or Fiddler.

### Modifying Swagger Response

I've just [added a change](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/7478a1b1b1b91d8fc1ead32bdec8a3dbf4ebc47e) in the latest v4.0.53 of ServiceStack that's now [available on MyGet](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/MyGet) that lets you alter the Swagger Response returned by ServiceStack you can use to populate **consumes** and **produces** at both the API Declaration and Operation level with:

```
Plugins.Add(new SwaggerFeature {
    ApiDeclarationFilter = x => 
      x.Consumes = x.Produces = new[] { MimeTypes.Json, MimeTypes.Xml }.ToList(),
    OperationFilter = x => 
      x.Consumes = x.Produces = new[] { MimeTypes.Json, MimeTypes.Xml }.ToList()
});
```

But this doesn't look like it has much of an effect to the Swagger UI, the only change I can see is the **body** parameter in **POST** requests now let you send XML:

[image]

Comment: I might be wrong (I am VERY new to ServiceStack), but I am not looking to "change" content types. My service already supports the various content-types (see default metadata page). I am trying to get the Swagger UI to display all the different ways of communicating with my service which includes content types other than JSON. 
As @wing328 says below, I am looking for a way to include all the content types that my service supports in Swaggers 'consumes' and 'produces' elements.
Again, feel free to correct me :)

Comment: @jk1990 I've updated the latest [v4.0.53 of ServiceStack on MyGet](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/MyGet) to let you modify the swagger response, but this doesn't look like it has much of an effect to Swagger UI.

Comment: Sweet! It works. It now sends requests with either XML and JSON content-types :D
It doesn't update the model schema in the UI as it does in swaggers own "petstore" demo. But it works :)
Thanks for the fast fix and response!

Answer (score 1):

In the Swagger spec (generated by ServiceStack), you need to update `produces` for the endpoint to include both "application/xml" and "application/json" if you want both to appear in the dropdown menu in swagger-ui.

Here is an example:

```
"produces": [
  "application/json",
  "application/xml"
],
```

Ref: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/blob/master/modules/swagger-codegen/src/test/resources/2_0/petstore.json#L77

OpenAPI Spec `produces`: https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#fixed-fields

Comment: Nice. Is it possible for me to add the application/xml from within my c# code?

Comment: I'm not sure how you generated the swagger spec from your ServiceStack code. If you're using Swashbuckle, then I think there's a way as I've seen people generate `produces` with multiple values.

Comment: I simply added the SwaggerFeature plugin.

Comment: I would suggest you to contact ServiceStack team as I'm not familiar with how ServiceStack generates the Swagger spec.